# axios.post doesn't return 400 with setTimeout wrapped around

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

```
app.post('/orders', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) 
    var apiKey = "";
    var apiSecret = "";
    var timestamp = Date.now();
    var payload = { market: req.body.market, order: { price: req.body.order.price, side: req.body.order.side, size: req.body.order.size } };
    var json = JSON.stringify(payload);
    var contentHash = cryptoJS.SHA512(json).toString(cryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    var parts = [
        timestamp,
        "POST",
        "test.com/orders",
        contentHash
    ];

    const signature = cryptoJS.HmacSHA512(parts.join(""), apiSecret).toString(cryptoJS.enc.Hex);

    var headers = {
        'api-key': apiKey,
        'content-hash': contentHash,
        'timestamp': timestamp,
        'signature': signature
    };

    setTimeout(function () {
         axios.post('https://test.com/orders', payload, { headers: headers })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 201) {
                    res.sendStatus(201);                    
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                res.status(500).send({ error: error });
            });
    }, 500);    
});
```

I was having trouble getting 400 response from the `test.com` endpoint and I found that when I wrapped around `axios.post()` with `setTimeout` it finally gave me 201 response. Why is this? how can I improve it better?

Comment: Are you making multiple requests in rapid succession and perhaps running into api request limit issues?

Comment: yeah good point, found that as soon as it hits `axios.post` line it goes straight to catch block then it comes back again to `res.sendStatus(201)`. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that if you did:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({payload, headers}));
setTimeout(function () {
     console.log(JSON.stringify({payload, headers}));
     axios.post('https://test.com/orders', payload, { headers: headers })
     // ...
}, 500);
```

you'll see that something is different.

This is a bit of an educated guess, so I could be way off.

```
app.post('/orders', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body) 
// more code

setTimeout(function () {
     axios.post('https://test.com/orders', payload, { headers: headers })
}, 500)
```

If that works, but when you remove `setTimeout` you get a 400 error, then I would bet dollars to donuts that

```
// more code
```

somewhere in there, when you are building `payload` (or maybe `headers`), you do something that is asynchronous (something returns a promise).  When you wait with `setTimeout`, the promise has resolved, it had some necessary side effect, and so it works.  When you don't, it doesn't.

Something like this:

```js
const handler = (x) => x.value === 2 ? console.log('201 Created') : console.log('400 Bad Request');

let req = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        req.value = 2
        resolve();
    }, 300); 
});

handler(req);

setTimeout(() => handler(req), 500);
```

Comment: Thanks! your answer does make sense. I just edited with my full code there. Basically, there is no asynchrounous operations (maybe not), but your example might be related.

Comment: can i asynchrounously call `// more code`? just started with nodejs a bit confusing

Comment: i'm not seeing any async code in what you posted.  My guess is probably wrong, but do the `console.log`s I put in my ffirst code block and see if they match.  If they do then I was definitely wrong, if they don't we can look at what is different

Comment: bad news, they match :(

`{"payload":{"market":"BTC-ETH","order":{"price":"0.02153666","side":"buy","size":"0.024"}},"headers":{"api-key":"same","content-hash":"same","timestamp":1589177505027,"signature":"same"}}

{"payload":{"market":"BTC-ETH","order":{"price":"0.02153666","side":"buy","size":"0.024"}},"headers":{"api-key":"same","content-hash":"same","timestamp":1589177505027,"signature":"same"}}
`

Comment: My next guess would be that they are checking the timestamp for some reason?  Maybe your clock is fast or theirs is slow, and by waiting 500ms after you make the timestamp they then consider it valid?  Probably not but try doing `var timestamp = Date.now() - 500` and see if it works without the timeout

Comment: omg you are genius that worked. Please edit your answer so I can accept it

Comment: but this is kinda miserable if it's clock related

Comment: at least you know.  should probably raise a support ticket with whatever site it is and let them know they should support some amount of clock skew

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience, you couldn’t pass variables directly inside the setTimeout function from out side. You can try creating a global variable and access it inside setTimeout function or try to use getFunction for access outside variable.

Comment: As a general statement this is not accurate. There are cases where using setTimeout used inside a for loop can have issues but those are far more specific than your general statement